# Sass filesystem cache error after deployment (`options=' for true:TrueClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sass

I have a large rails project running on multiple instances (nginx + thin). For some time now I've been experiencing an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `options=' for true:TrueClass (in [...]/app/assets/stylesheets/stylesheet-3.css.scss.erb)
```

shortly after each each redeploy. After some research (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4648) I've established that the problem is rooted in Sass caching mechanism (we use sass 3.2.1 and sass-rails 3.2.5).
Reading related Sass code I've backtraced the errors to EOFError, TypeError, ArgumentError or LoadError exception, raised in `Sass::CacheStores::Filesystem::_retrieve`.

My problem is, I can't ever manage to replicate this error in a controlled (local) environment and I also can't afford to introduce random changes to see what happens.

Does anyone know what the real (underlying) reason of this problem might be?

Comment: Hi. I came across this error as well. I am not sure why it happened but as suggested it might be due to duplicate mix in names, at least that was what happened to me. Clearing the tmp folder solved it for me if it helps.

Comment: Clearing _tmp_ was not a viable solution for me. I've ended up disabling sass cache altogether, which increased compilation times by 50%, but since we cache compiled stylesheets anyway, it wasn't much of a problem.